# WordPress Referrer Tracking

Tags: php, asp.net, wordpress

I have a WordPress blog that's hosted within my site (http://www.mysite.com/blog) and my website itself is based on ASP.NET.

I'm tracking referrers within ASP.NET upon session start and storing them within a session variable to save into my database either after a session expires or after a visitor converts to a member.

How can I track the referrers for visitors that come to the blog first and click on a link to a page within the website? Is there a way in WordPress that I could pass the referrer using a query string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When they land on the blog drop a cookie with the original referrer.

Then read this from the app.

Whip up a plugin to do something like this:

```
if( !isset($_COOKIE['ref']) ) {
    setcookie(...);
}
```

If you feel like a hack you could just add this to WP's index.php, but a plugin would be the more portable, clean option.